# Consuming AWS Kinesis Stream using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am looking to consume a AWS Kinesis Stream using Node.js. Can someone provide with working samples.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly i would suggest you to go through the Kinesis documentation for reading data from Kinesis stream. Here is a [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/building-consumers.html).

To consume a kinesis stream you can make use of Kinesis Client Library(KCL) for nodejs. Here is a [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-implementation-app-nodejs.html) for that.

You can find examples code in the above link. Refer [basic-sample](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-nodejs/tree/master/samples/basic_sample) github repo.